# How to not repeat the if statements and allow it to look them up somehow? I am very new, im sure this is basic

Tags: c++, c, mbed

I am very new and was wondering if there was a way to make the code look up the if statements rather than having to copy and past them

Also any other tips on how to clean this up is much appreciated, not a serious project just playing around and trying to learn

This code is done on mbed using Nucleo board to get the output

```
#include "mbed.h" 
#include "../lib/uopmsb/uop_msb_2_0_0.h"
using namespace uop_msb_200;

Buzzer buzz;

DigitalOut greenLED(LED1);
DigitalOut blueLED(LED2);
DigitalOut redLED(LED3);


int main()
 {     while(true)
 {

    greenLED = 1; 
    blueLED = 0;
    redLED = 0;
    if( greenLED == 1 )
 {
 buzz.playTone("C");
 }
 else {
 NULL;
 }
 if( blueLED == 1 )
 {
 buzz.playTone("D");
 }
 else {
 NULL;
 }
 if( redLED == 1 )
 {
 buzz.playTone("G");
 }
 else {
 NULL;
 }
    wait_us(2500000); 

    greenLED = 0;
    blueLED = 1;
    redLED = 0;
    if( greenLED == 1 )
{
 buzz.playTone("C");
 }
 else {
 NULL;
 }
 if( blueLED == 1 )
 {
 buzz.playTone("D");
 }
 else {
 NULL;
 }
 if( redLED == 1 )
 {
 buzz.playTone("G");
 }
 else {
 NULL;
 }
    wait_us(2500000); 

    greenLED = 0;
    blueLED = 0;
    redLED = 1;
    if( greenLED == 1 )
 {
 buzz.playTone("C");
 }
 else {
 NULL;
 }
 if( blueLED == 1 )
 {
 buzz.playTone("D");
 }
 else {
 NULL;
 }
 if( redLED == 1 )
 {
 buzz.playTone("G");
 }
 else {
 NULL;
 }
    wait_us(2500000); 

    greenLED = 0;
    blueLED = 0;
    redLED = 0;
    if( greenLED == 1 )
 {
 buzz.playTone("C");
 }
 else {
 NULL;
 }
 if( blueLED == 1 )
 {
 buzz.playTone("D");
 }
 else {
 NULL;
 }
 if( redLED == 1 )
 {
 buzz.playTone("G");
 }
 else {
 NULL;
 }
  }
   }
```

Comment: Make a function with the check logic in it and then call the function as many times as you like with any parameter values needed.

Comment: Please fix your code formatting.

Comment: @jwdonahue sorry, i'm new! just copy and pasted from mbed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could always make a void function like this before the main function, this will let you call it, run what ever is inside and then return back to the main function.

```
void play(){
    if( greenLED == 1 ){
     buzz.playTone("C");
    }
    if( blueLED == 1 ){
     buzz.playTone("D");
    }
    if( redLED == 1 ){
     buzz.playTone("G");
    }
 }
```

So youll implement it like this, calling the function everytime you want to play a sound.

```
Buzzer buzz;

    DigitalOut greenLED(LED1);
    DigitalOut blueLED(LED2);
    DigitalOut redLED(LED3);

void play(){
    if( greenLED == 1 ){
     buzz.playTone("C");
    }
    if( blueLED == 1 ){
     buzz.playTone("D");
    }
    if( redLED == 1 ){
     buzz.playTone("G");
    }
 }



int main(){ 
    while(true){

    greenLED = 1; 
    blueLED = 0;
    redLED = 0;

    play();

    wait_us(2500000);

    greenLED = 0; 
    blueLED = 1;
    redLED = 0;

    play();

    wait_us(2500000);
```

And then itterate turning your led's on and off etc.

Comment: also if your just trying to turn an led on and play a sound you could just make a void function for every led turning on and playing the sound, and then just call those functions in main().

Comment: thank you so much! been searching for hours. Was just trying to play around with making code more presentable and minimise repeating! will defo use this cheers

Comment: hey, no problem, and another good practice is to use comments around what some functions do, this helps you and other people read it in case you start having problems, or forget what something does.